# how to pass data from one page to another using query in iPhone phone gap application

Tags: jquery, iphone, cordova

In my application, I have 2 pages, page1 and page2. In page1, I have one text field and one label. I want to pass these two values from page1 to page2 and to insert them as text for 2 labels respectively when click on submit button. I'm new to Phonegap and jQuery. How can i achieve this using jQuery and Javascript?

```
{
    var name = document.getElementById("usernameTextField").value;   //TextField
    var fullname = document.getElementById("nameLabel").innerHTML;  //label
    localstorage.setItem("userName", name);
    localstorage.setItem("fullname1", fullname); 
    var getusername = localstorage.getItem("userName");
    var getname = localstorage.getItem("fullname1");
    fullnameLabel.innerHTML = getname.value;  //label
    userNameLabel.innerHTML = getusername.value;  //label
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `localStorage` to achieve this. New in HTML5, it allows for persistent storage client-side.

`localStorage` uses key/value pairs.

`localStorage.setItem("Key-name", itemData);`

`localStorage.getItem("Key-name");`

`localStorage.removeItem("Key-name");`

Comment: Do i need to write all these in javascript file?

Comment: only the bits you need. I was just saying there are three methods available to you (set, get, remove). But yes, they are javascript.

Comment: @user25 Then I suggest posting your code so people can help you by troubleshooting.

Comment: var name = document.getElementById("usernameTextField").value;   //TextField
    var fullname = document.getElementById("nameLabel").innerHTML;  //label
    localstorage.setItem("userName", name);
    localstorage.setItem("fullname1", fullname); 
    var getusername = localstorage.getItem("userName");
    var getname = localstorage.getItem("fullname1");
    fullnameLabel.innerHTML = getname.value;  //label
    userNameLabel.innerHTML = getusername.value;  //label

Answer (score 1):

Make use of localStorage.It is the best option to transfer the data between pages

read about it here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pass simple text data you can also use query parameters (home.html?text=test).

Here a link how to get there parameters in javascript:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

This way is maybe a little bit faster because you dont have to use the js bridge and file IO on the device... but it should not realy matter =)